# Get keys of $_FILES array

Tags: php

Is there any way of getting the keys of the file upload input field named upload[] after form submission?

```
    <input type="file" name="upload[3]" />
    <input type="file" name="upload[7]" />
    <input type="file" name="upload[10]" />
```

Answer (score 7):

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will give you all keys.

```
$keys = array_keys($_FILES["upload"]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the $_FILES array. Outputs: name type tmp_name error size

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the array naming hack, note that $_FILES is built in an incredibly moronic way, you'll get this structure:

```
$_FILES = array(
   'upload' => 
        'name' => array(
           '3' => 'name of file #3',
           '7' => 'name of file #7', 
           etc...
        ),
        'type' => array(
           '3' => 'mime type of file #3',
           etc...
       etc..
    );
```

To retrieve the 3,7,etc.. keys, you'll need `array_keys($_FILES['upload'])`

Don't know what the PHP devs were smoking that day, but `$_FILES['upload'][3]['name']` **SHOULD** have been the structure... All of a file's data in a single child array, not spread across 6 different ones.

Answer (score 2):

use `$_FILES["upload"]` to get the keys.
for more [information](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload[3]" />
    <input type="file" name="upload[7]" />
    <input type="file" name="upload[10]" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
    <?php
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES['upload']);
}
?>
```

Output is

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [3] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
            [7] => 
            [10] => 
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [3] => image/jpeg
            [7] => 
            [10] => 
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [3] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpD249.tmp
            [7] => 
            [10] => 
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [3] => 0
            [7] => 4
            [10] => 4
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [3] => 879394
            [7] => 0
            [10] => 0
        )

)
```